# Start new intent on ShowcaseViews button

Tags: java, android, android-intent, showcaseview

I was wondering how to start a new intent if the user presses a button in my Android in-app tutorial (ShowcaseViews).  Here is my ShowcaseViews class:

```
public class ShowcaseViews {

private final List<ShowcaseView> views = new ArrayList<ShowcaseView>();
private final Activity activity;
private final int showcaseTemplateId;

private interface OnShowcaseAcknowledged {
    void onShowCaseAcknowledged(ShowcaseView oldView);
}

/**
 * @param activity               The activity containing the views you wish to showcase
 * @param showcaseTemplateLayout Must be the layout of a ShowcaseView - use this to style your showcase
 */
public ShowcaseViews(Activity activity, int showcaseTemplateLayout) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.showcaseTemplateId = showcaseTemplateLayout;
}

public void addView(ItemViewProperties properties) {
    ShowcaseView viewTemplate = newInstanceOfShowcaseView();
    viewTemplate.setShowcaseItem(properties.itemType, properties.id, activity);
    viewTemplate.setText(properties.titleResId, properties.messageResId);
    setChainClickListener(viewTemplate);
    views.add(viewTemplate);
}

public void addView(ViewProperties properties) {
    ShowcaseView viewTemplate = newInstanceOfShowcaseView();
    View v = activity.findViewById(properties.id);
    viewTemplate.setShowcaseView(v);
    viewTemplate.setText(properties.titleResId, properties.messageResId);
    setChainClickListener(viewTemplate);
    views.add(viewTemplate);
}

private ShowcaseView newInstanceOfShowcaseView() {
    return (ShowcaseView) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(showcaseTemplateId, null);
}

private void setChainClickListener(final ShowcaseView viewTemplate) {
    viewTemplate.overrideButtonClick(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            acknowledgedListener.onShowCaseAcknowledged(viewTemplate);
        }
    });
}

private OnShowcaseAcknowledged acknowledgedListener = new OnShowcaseAcknowledged() {
    @Override
    public void onShowCaseAcknowledged(ShowcaseView oldView) {
        oldView.hide();
        show();
    }
};

/**
 * Showcases will be shown in the order they where added, continuing when the button is pressed
 */
public void show() {
    if (views.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    final ShowcaseView view = views.get(0);
    ((ViewGroup) activity.getWindow().getDecorView()).addView(view);
    views.remove(0);
}

/**
 * Used for views on the ActionBar
 */
public static class ItemViewProperties extends ViewProperties {
    public static final int ID_SPINNER = 0;
    public static final int ID_TITLE = 0;
    protected final int itemType;

    public ItemViewProperties(int id, int titleResId, int messageResId, int itemType) {
        super(id, titleResId, messageResId);
        this.itemType = itemType;
    }
}

/**
 * Used for all views except those on the ActionBar
 */
public static class ViewProperties {
    protected final int titleResId;
    protected final int messageResId;
    protected final int id;

    public ViewProperties(int id, int titleResId, int messageResId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.titleResId = titleResId;
        this.messageResId = messageResId;
    }
}

}
```

Here is my MainActivity class:

```
 public void showcaseSecondActivity() {
    ShowcaseViews views = new ShowcaseViews(CameraTestActivity.this, R.layout.view_showcase);
    views.addView(new ShowcaseViews.ItemViewProperties(0, R.string.showcase_main_spinner_title, R.string.showcase_main_spinner_message, ShowcaseView.ITEM_ACTION_HOME));
    Intent intent = new Intent(CameraTestActivity.this, UserSettingsActivity.class);
    views.show();
}
```

Here is my view_showcase XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This is our ShowCase template that we will use
  whenever we want to showcase an item.
  Here we can customise the colors of the showcase. -->
<com.rohit.ShowcaseView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:showcaseview="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.rohit"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
showcaseview:sv_backgroundColor="@color/showcase_background"
showcaseview:sv_buttonText="@string/showcase_button_ok" />
```

If I add `startActivity(intent)` after `views.show()` in my MainActivity class, it doesn't even show the dialog and goes straight to the intent.  I want to open the activity AFTER the user has clicked the button.  I don't know to proceed.  I am quite new to this and I have searched all over SO and Google.  Any help regarding this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
showcaseView.setOnShowcaseEventListener(new OnShowcaseEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShowcaseViewShow(ShowcaseView arg0) { }

    @Override
    public void onShowcaseViewHide(ShowcaseView arg0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(SignIn.this,MainFragmentActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onShowcaseViewDidHide(ShowcaseView arg0) { }
});
```

Comment: Provide details on what your code does, a code-only answer doesn't explain itself.